# Changing tooltip icon on field condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, material-ui

I'm trying to implement a tooltip for an INPUT field which should change the icon on some condition.
The very basic usage is the password field on a registration form.
Need a suggestion on how to properly do it.

At the moment I have:

```
      <Tooltip title={<div><ArrowRightIcon /> 8 characters<br /> <ArrowRightIcon /> 1 letter <br /> <ArrowRightIcon /> 1 special symbol<br /><ArrowRightIcon /> 1 number</div>} arrow>


      <Input
        
        id="standard-adornment-password"
        type={values.showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
        value={values.password}
        onChange={handleChange('password')}
        
        endAdornment={
          <InputAdornment position="end">
            <IconButton
              aria-label="toggle password visibility"
              onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
              onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword}
            >
              {values.showPassword ? <Visibility /> : <VisibilityOff />}
            </IconButton>
          </InputAdornment>
        }
      />
      </Tooltip>
```

I want the "ArrowRightIcon" icon to be changed to "CheckIcon" once the condition is true.

Please assist on the correct implementation.

Comment: You can always use a ternary expression anywhere in your JSX: `{var ? <TrueIcon /> : <FalseIcon />}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some improvements that can still be made here, but the general idea is this:

```js
<Tooltip title={<div>
    { values.password.length >= 8 ? <ArrowRightIcon /> : <CheckIcon /> }
    { /* Repeat for your other conditions. */ }
</div>}>
...
</Tooltip>
```

If you want to get really fancy and avoid code duplication, you could set up an array of predicates and iterate through them:

```js
const passwordChecks = [
    { check: (password) => password.length >= 8, message: "8 characters" },
    // ...
];
```

```js
<Tooltip title={<div>{passwordChecks.map(check => <span>
    {check.validate(password) ? <ArrowRightIcon /> : <CheckIcon />}{" "}
    {check.message}
</span>)}</div>}>
...
</Tooltip>
```